# Add label/text to esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, markers

How can I add label or text on the ESRI's PictureMarkerSymbol (Javascript API)?

I could use any other marker as well that support labels.

Comment: I have similar requirement. I am new to ArcGis, i need complete code of how to add dynamic text on the marker symbol. I have Location Data in Json format.... {locations: [{latitude: 52.1, longitude: 4.1, textToDisplayOnThePictureMarkerSymbol: 34}, {latitude: 52.2, longitude: 4.9, textToDisplayOnThePictureMarkerSymbol: 50}, ...]} Pls help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the marker and then add textSymbol to show labels on the markers. Like this:

```
var markerGraphic = layer.add(new esri.Graphic(point, new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol('images/pin.png', 38, 44).setOffset(0,15)));
var textSymbol = layer.add(new esri.Graphic(point, new esri.symbol.TextSymbol(counter).setOffset(0,12)));
```